# forms field not loading

Tags: django, forms, model

I have designed a model in Django and a form according to it. The below are the both files.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class TotalEvent(models.Model):
    CustomerID = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    eventID = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    eventPlace = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    eventStartTime = models.TimeField(auto_now=False)
    eventDate = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from catering.models import TotalEvent   

class TotalEventForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TotalEvent
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now, When in my html file I tried this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Log-in{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Detail page</h1>
    <p>Enter your schedule details here</p>
    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
       {% for field in forms %}
          {{field}}
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
       {% endfor %}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from catering.forms import TotalEvent


def add(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
    form = TotalEvent(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {    'form': TotalEvent()
  })
```

In the output it shows no input fields except the following output
`Enter your schedule details here`

Please have a look and let me know where is the error.

Comment: add your views.py to question

Comment: check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#the-template

Comment: @Satendra Added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TotalEventForm` instead `TotalEvent` as `TotalEvent` is model class not form class, update your views.py

```
def add(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = TotalEventForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

  # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
  else:
     form = TotalEventForm()

  return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

and you can use *form* directly in your html file.

```
<form method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form }}
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: its gives an error `form.save(): syntax error`  at line 13 at views.py

Comment: remove that line, i have updated my answer please check, as form is already saved inside is_valid() method

Comment: Its the same output. i changed all the code according to the updated question.

Comment: have you made changes to your html

Comment: form is not visible.

Comment: This is strange, please check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#the-template

Comment: Following Satendra's recommendation to change TotalEvent() to TotalEventForm() did you also change the import at the top of the views.py to : from catering.forms import TotalEventForm  because you are trying to import a form that does not exist.  See in your forms.py you have declared TotalEventForm but you appear to be importing TotalEvent.

Answer (score 0):

type

```
{% for field in form %}
```

instead of

```
{% for field in forms %}
```